# How can I obtain the top 100 sales ranked items on Amazon programatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I took a look through the API documentation and since the `ItemSearch` operation requires the `Keywords` parameter, I do not think it will be possible but I just want to confirm.

Should I be looking at a different operation?

Comment: Do you want to know the top 100 sales ranked items of all the items in Amazon? Or all of them in a specific category (and how specific can you get?) You will not be able to query against all the items Amazon sells, to the best of my knowledge, but you can query against a subcategory.

Answer (score 3):

Use an XML parser.

Amazon has the bestsellers feed at:

http://www.amazon.ca/rss/bestsellers/books/ref=pd_ts_rss_link

Comment: Unfortunately, the RSS links only show the top ten top sellers

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a means to obtain the top 100, but the [TopSellers](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01/DG/) ResponseGroup can be used on the [BrowseNodeLookup](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01/DG/) operation to return the top 10 items in a given BrowseNodeId. The BrowseNodeId identifies a product category.

If you are interested in a set of categories, retrieving the top 10 items from each category might be an acceptable compromise